# trying to fetch data from AWS Amplify Datastore but error is coming

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-datastore

trying to fetch data from AWS Amplify Datastore but warnings are coming and i am getting an empty result but the data is there in datastore please help!!

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGbUV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYkKs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gQC9.jpg)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.